# java.io.IOException: Stream closed in HandlerInterceptor

Tags: java, spring

I have a problem with Interceptor in SpringBoot I am trying to read the body in a request at preHandle() method.

```
    public class LogInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter  {

        @Override
        public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler)
                throws Exception {
 StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();  
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;  

            try {  
                InputStream inputStream = request.getInputStream(); 

                if (inputStream != null) {  
                    bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));  

                    char[] charBuffer = new char[128];  
                    int bytesRead = -1;  

                    while ((bytesRead = bufferedReader.read(charBuffer)) > 0) {  
                        stringBuilder.append(charBuffer, 0, bytesRead);  
                    }  
                } else {  
                    stringBuilder.append("");  
                }  
            } catch (IOException ex) {  
                System.out.println("Error reading the request body...");  
            } finally {  
                if (bufferedReader != null) {  
                    try {  
                        bufferedReader.close();  
                    } catch (IOException ex) {  
                        System.out.println("Error closing bufferedReader...");  
                    }  
                }  
            }


            String body = stringBuilder.toString();  
            System.out.println("--Body--"+body); 
    }
}
```

This code print body correctly but when I try to made a POST petition with Postman I receive the following error.

```
I/O error while reading input message; nested exception is java.io.IOException: Stream closed
```

If I do the same petition witouth this code the petition works correctly.

Could anyone help to me ? Or said a better solution to intercept body ?